# Focus a input text(location, written by p-autocomplete) on page load in angular

Tags: angular

I need to focus the input text(used p-autocomplete component) on page load in angular.

I have written autofocus in  but my code is not working as expected

My code:

```
<p-autocomplete (onFocus)=showLocationTip() required="true" name="location" inputId="location>
```

Comment: I have written "autofocus" in "p-autocomplete" tag but my code is not working as expected

Comment: please add some code examples of what do you have so people can see what are you doing wrong

Comment: <p-autocomplete (onFocus)=showLocationTip()  required="true" name="location" inputId="location>

Comment: I need to call this id in onInit() function in .ts file

Answer (score 0):

In you component.html  file:-

```
<p-autocomplete #inputField (onFocus)=showLocationTip() required="true" name="location" inputId="location>
```

In your component.ts file:-

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';


export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('inputField', { static: false }) inputField: ElementRef;

          ngAfterViewInit() {
              const el: HTMLElement = this.inputField.nativeElement;
              el.focus();
          }
         showLocationTip(e) {
             // your code here
             console.log(e);
         }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :), I am using @viewChild('location'):NgModel, please help how to get the focus event for this element